# Keeping objects in complex object tree in sync

Tags: c#, oop, observer-pattern

Say I have the following object tree.  My object tree is not really this stupid, but it does have a number of many-to-many relationships

```
Account
 - Users {UserId, Name, etc}
 - UserPermissions {User object, Permission object}
 - Permissions {PermissionId, Name, etc}
```

Say, I want to delete a User or a Permission object from under the Account object.  I'd like in either scenario for any UserPermission objects that contain the deleted item to be also removed from UserPermission collection.

Is there an elegant way of doing so, without manually removing UserPermission objects?  I know objects from Entity Framework models do this, but not sure how I can achieve the same results... I am not using EF but am instead saving object structures to RavenDb.

**Per request, here is a more comprehensive data model**

```
public class Account
{
    public List<User> Users {get;set;}
    public List<UserGroup> UserGroups {get;set;}
    public List<Alert> Alerts {get;set;}
    public List<Resource> Resources {get;set;}
    public List<AlertSubscription> AlertSubscriptions {get;set;}
}
public class UserGroup : IAlertSubscriber
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public List<User> Users {get;set;}
}
public class User : IAlertSubscriber
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
public class AlertSubscription
{
    public Alert Alert {get;set;}
    public List<Resources> AlertPublishers {get;set;}
    public List<IAlertSubscribers> AlertTargets {get;set;}
    public int MinimumSeverity {get;set;}
}
```

So, what I'd love to be able to do is if I remove a User from Account.Users collection, to also nuke it from various AlertTargets, UserGroups, etc.  If I remove UserGroup from Account.UserGroups, I want to nuke it from AlertTargets, if I remove a Resource from Account.Resources to also nuke it from AlertSubsciptions...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to sync two copies of same data, I would go with single copy. You can either have only list of UserPermissions, and two other collections be calculated:

```
public class Account
{
    private List<UserPermission> _userPersmission;

    public List<UserPermission> UserPermissions
    {
        get { return _userPersmission; }
        set { _userPersmission = value; }
    }

    public IEnumerable<User> Users
    {
        get { return _userPersmission.Select(up => up.User); }
    }

    public IEnumerable<Permission> Permissions
    {
        get { return _userPersmission.Select(up => up.Permission); }
    }
}
```

or calculate UserPermissions based on two other collections. But I would prefer previous approach, thus UserPermission can have additional data.

UPDATE: If you cannot calculate all collections from some of them without duplicating data, then you are back to Observer. Subject in your case is different collections, like Users. And subjects should notify other collections if some item is removed. [`BindingList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a subject which implements such notification. Unfortunately it does not provide information about which item was removed, so you will need to create custom binding list:

```
public class ExtendedBindingList<T> : BindingList<T>
{
    public T LastRemovedItem { get; private set; }

    protected override void RemoveItem(int index)
    {
        LastRemovedItem = base[index];
        base.RemoveItem(index);            
    }
}
```

You can use it to get notification about item removing:

```
public class Account
{
    public ExtendedBindingList<User> Users { get; private set; }

    public Account()
    {
        Users = new ExtendedBindingList<User>();
        Users.ListChanged += Users_ListChanged;
    }

    private void Users_ListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ListChangedType != ListChangedType.ItemDeleted)
            return;

        foreach (var group in UserGroups)
            group.Users.Remove(Users.LastRemovedItem);
    }

    // ...
 }
```

Another option is usage of methods `AddUser` and `RemoveUser` for modification of users list. And exposing users list as `IEnumerable`:

```
public class Account
{
    private List<User> _users = new List<User>();

    public IEnumerable<User> Users { get; }

    public void AddUser(User use)
    {
        _users.Add(user);
    }

    public void RemoveUser(User user)
    {
        _users.Remove(user);

        foreach (var group in UserGroups)
            group.Users.Remove(user);
    }

    // ...
 }
```

Comment: this breaks down as soon as there is another many-to-many relationship that involves either Users or Permissions, does it not?

Comment: @Igorek it would be nice to see sample which reflects your real problem

Comment: @Igorek with updated model you still can avoid duplication of data - use UserGroups and AlertSubscriptions. Other collections (Users, Alerts, Resources) could be calculated from these two

Comment: Stil dont think this will worki.  A User does not have to belong to a UserGroup or (s)he can can belong to more than one UserGroup.

Comment: @Igorek getting users from groups is simple: `UserGroups.SelectMany(ug => ug.Users).Distinct()`. But if there is users which do not belong to any groups.. value cannot be calculated

Comment: I mean that a user can either belong to 0 groups, one group or many groups.  I dont see how I can keep a single user object under a single usergroup as you suggest.

Comment: Thanks... after edit it makes more sense and looks like ObservableCollection maybe slightly more featureful than BindingList... I cant use custom Add/Remove methods due to objects being serialized/deserialized from RavenDb

Comment: @Igorek yep, agree with you `ObservableCollection` might be more appropriate here